# Writing a CakePHP find Join

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a SQL query that I'm trying to convert into a CakePHP find, but I'm not sure how to structure it... could someone please provide a little assistance?

```
SELECT texts.*, people.id, people.first_name, people.last_name FROM texts 
    NATURAL JOIN (
         SELECT person_id, MAX(id) AS id
         FROM texts 
         WHERE texts.status = 'received' 
         GROUP BY person_id
    ) t RIGHT JOIN people ON people.id = t.person_id
    WHERE texts.body is not null
    AND texts.created > '$since'
    AND person.counselor_id = '2' 
    ORDER BY texts.created DESC
```

**Here is what I have**

```
    $texts = $this->find('all', array(
        'recursive' => -1,
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' =>  'texts',
                'alias' =>  't',
                'type'  =>  'NATURAL',
                'conditions'    =>   array('t.status' => 'received')
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'people',
                'alias' => 'Person',
                'type' => 'RIGHT',
                'conditions' => 'people.id = t.person_id'
            )   
        ),
        'conditions' => array('AND' => array('Text.body IS NOT NULL', 'Text.created > 0000-00-00 00:00:00')),
        'order' => 'Text.created DESC'
    ));
```

**This is the SQL it writes**

```
SELECT Text.id, Text.person_id, Text.sid, Text.to, Text.from, Text.body, Text.status, 
     Text.direction, Text.owner, Text.counselor_read, Text.created, Text.modified 
FROM admissionsedge_penfield.texts AS Text 
NATURAL JOIN admissionsedge_penfield.texts 
AS t ON (t.status = 'received') 
RIGHT JOIN admissionsedge_penfield.people AS Person ON (people.id = t.person_id) 
WHERE ((Text.body IS NOT NULL) AND (Text.created > 0000-00-00 00:00:00)) 
ORDER BY Text.created DESC
```

Thank you!

Comment: I stand corrected.  The remaining item is the derived table is not the same. A recommendation (hopefully better than my last) is to make the derived table a MySQL view, then reference the view in the cakephp join clause.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any models defined?  If so, you need to share them, along with which one you would expect to perform the find because the **right join** is not generally used AND a **Natural Join** is not used.

Assuming you do not...

In the controller, run the query above with this code. *{The $recordset assignment line would be where a find method would generally go}*

```
$some_sql = 'your sql statement';
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$recordset = $db->rawQuery($some_sql);
set('recordset', $recordset);
```

If you want to leverage CakePHP's MVC, then I suggest this query be rewritten as left joins and inner joins

Comment: would be better to call query on the (e.g.) `Text` model, or to call `$this->Text->putnamehere()` method which encapsulates the call to query - i.e. avoid putting sql in controllers since they shouldn't know/care about sql at all. The advice about restructuring the query to use LEFT/RIGHT joins appears to be appropriate, as such +1.